# Step definition method is not running when feature is run

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-behave

I have installed `Gerkin Plugin` and `Behave` lib to implement BDD automation.
Created directory features in the root folder of the project. under the feature folder created steps directory.
Then created `run.feature` file in features folder and `run_steps.py` file in steps folder.

run `behave` command and getting:

```py
Feature: Test # features/run.feature:1

  @test
  Scenario: run a simple test  # features/run.feature:5
    Given Run first test       # features/steps/run_steps.py:11

1 feature passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped
1 scenario passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped
1 step passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped, 0 undefined
Took 0m0.054s

(venv) C:\Users\Dzmitry\PycharmProjects\test>behave
Feature: Test # features/run.feature:1

  @test
  Scenario: run a simple test  # features/run.feature:5
    Given Run first test       # features/steps/run_steps.py:11

1 feature passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped
1 scenario passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped
1 step passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped, 0 undefined
Took 0m0.047s
```

but code that is implemented in the method(function) is not running.
Could you please suggest. I also trying to run as `behave features/run.feature` - result is the same

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think that the step implementation is not executed ?

The behave output indicates:

- behave can find the step implementation in file "features/steps/run_steps.py" at line 11
- Summary report indicates that the step is executed: `1 step passed, ...`

SANITY CHECK:

Inject a failure in the step implementation (like: `1/0` which raises as DivisionByZeroError or raise an RuntimeError("XXX")) and run behave again. You should get an error during the execution (StackTrace, ...)